# Angular2 typescript global provider resolve using Interface

Tags: typescript, angular

My angular2 app has 2 services `WebStorageService` and `MobileStorageService` which implements an Interface `IStorageService`. In my `main.component` I bootstrap the app with `WebStorageService` and in one of the components I am trying to get the the provider in the constructor as below,

```
// main.component
bootstrap(AppComponent,[WebStorageService])  // WebStorageService implements IStorageService interface

//AppComponent
import {IStorageService} from "./IStorageService"

@Component
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private _storage: IStorageService) { } <-- throws an error Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent

}
```

So, is there any way to provide the service using the Interface as the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using angular2 opaque tokens along with @rinukkusu answer.

```
// main.component
bootstrap(AppComponent,[{provide: globalStorageService, {useClass: WebStorage} }])  

// where globalStorageService is an opaque token
export let globalStorageService = new Token("IStorageService"); 

//AppComponent   
@Component
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(@Inject(globalStorageService) _storage:IStorageService){}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use interfaces for DI. Compilation removes interface information and it is therefore not available at runtime. Interfaces are for static analysis only.

Answer (score -1):

Add the provider to your component:

```
 @Component({
   providers: [IStorageService]})
    export class AppComponent {

      constructor(private _storage: IStorageService) { } 

    }
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem at all. Angular 2 can't resolve the interface on its own and create an instance of it.